# Struct in function - differences

Tags: c, function, struct

What is the proper way to passing struct into function?
Both solutions works fine, but is there any significant difference?

```
 struct sensor
{
    int32_t temperature;

}BME280;

int32_t read_temperature(struct sensor *BME)
{
}
```

vs

```
 typedef struct sensor
{
    int32_t temperature;

}BME2801;

int32_t read_temperature(BME2801 *BME)
{
}

int main(void)
{
    BME2801 BME280;
}
```

Comment: There's absolutely no difference. A typedef just lets you create a short synonym.

Comment: Note that the two codes aren't equivalent. The first one declares a global variable that contains one of those structures, the second one just declares a typedef.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! Yep, If i declare BME280 as a global variable in second example it will be equivalent - right?

Comment: If you just want to define the structure, don't put `BME280` at the end.

Comment: If you've created a typedef that usually indicates you intend to use it. Not using it means you've got useless code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first example, you are defining a structure of type `struct sensor`, and declaring a global variable called `BME280` of the same type. Your `read_temperature` function is taking a pointer to a `struct sensor`. Your variable `BME280` is not being used for anything.

In the second example, you are defining a structure of type `struct sensor`, and using `typedef` to create a new type name (`BME2801`), which will allow you to type `BME2801` instead of `struct sensor` in your code. In your `main` function you are declaring a `BME2801` (aka `struct sensor`) type variable with the name `BME280`. Your `read_temperature` function works the same, just as before.

These are two different examples and definitely not equivalent.

Your use of pointers to pass your structure by reference is good. Typically you want to pass all structures using pointers, especially if it is particularly big `struct`. Just cut out `BME280` from your first example and you're golden.

Now comes the question of whether to use `typedef` to create a new type name to refer to a `struct sensor`. If it improves legibility and clarity, by all means do it. Assuming you want to refer to each `struct sensor` as `BME2801`, your second example does it correctly. I would argue that `struct sensor` is significantly clearer than `BME2801` though. Usually you would define your structure in one of two ways and use it thusly:

```
struct sensor
{
    int32_t temperature;
};

int32_t read_temperature (struct sensor *BME)
{
}

int main (void)
{
    struct sensor BME280;

    /* Initialize your struct with appropriate values here */

    read_temperature (&BME280);
}
```

Or you can use `typedef`. This is typically done with structures to remove the requirement to use the keyword `struct`. C++ does this automatically without the explicit `typedef`.

```
typedef struct sensor
{
    int32_t temperature;
}sensor;
/* 'sensor' now refers to the type 'struct sensor' */

int32_t read_temperature (sensor *BME)
{
}

int main (void)
{
    sensor BME280;

    /* Initialize your struct with appropriate values here */

    read_temperature (&BME280);
}
```

Whether to `typedef` a `struct` to simply omit the `struct` keyword is a matter of style. [The Linux kernel coding style](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/process/coding-style.rst) suggests almost never using a `typedef` for structures unless you actively hiding its contents and encourage developers using your `struct` to use special accessor functions you provided. I follow this advice in my own code, but there are other opinions out there.